# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my rails app on EC2 instance and using capistrano. 
I am getting 404 not found error for assets file tried so many solutions

```
http://52.36.187.96/assets/jquery.fancybox-buttons-bc75396a9f71beda584274c69d094623.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://52.36.187.96/assets/application-e80ce0393dc75b248766cc80da46f627.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

when i ssh into instance i can see assets file under shared/public/assets folder

Comment: Within the current symlink, does public/assets/jquery.fancybox-buttons-bc75396a9f71beda584274c69d094623.css exist? If so, is your webserver pointing to public/ as the webroot?

Comment: Can you please explain, new to the dev ops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out out i had to change my server configuration root
Try changing

```
nginx root /home/deploy/app_name/public; to /home/deploy/app_name/current/public;
```

in nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.